# Printing loop variable changes var value

Tags: c, pointers, gcc, mingw

Here are my two structures :

```
int *data = malloc(sizeof(int) * 512 * 512);
int **sortedData = malloc(sizeof(int) * 512);
```

The data var contains integers from a file. sortedData is supposed to be a 2D version of data. Here is how I initialize it :

```
for (int i = 0; i < dimensions[0]; i++)
    {
        sortedData[i] = (data + i * 512);
    }
```

For testing the values I use :

```
    printf("%d\n", data[0]);
    printf("%d\n", sortedData[0][0]);`
```

The problem is that the outcome of the second printf is an address, so the values are :

```
81
44766304
```

I tried to print the value of (data + i * 512) like this :

```
for (int i = 0; i < dimensions[0]; i++)
    {
        printf("%d\n", data + i * 512);
        sortedData[i] = (data + i * 512);
    }
```

And here is the thing : The printf returns an address for each i, but now, the outcome of the program is what I am looking for :

```
81
81
```

I can't really understand how the printf would change the returned value and why my initial solution is wrong.

EDIT 1 : It still doesn't work after changing sortedData from

```
... = malloc(sizeof(int) * 512);
```

To

```
... = malloc(sizeof(int *) * 512);
```

Comment: `int **sortedData = malloc(sizeof(int) * 512);` => `int **sortedData = malloc(sizeof(int *) * 512);` your elements are pointers not integers

Comment: if someone finds a better duplicate, be my guest to edit. But it's a common error, so I'm closing, my answer explains the exact same issue

Comment: I changed the malloc as you said, but it still doesn't work. The printf is still the only way to get what I am looking for.

Comment: what is `dimensions[0]` ? is that 512? are you sure ?

Comment: could you create a [mcve] that runs and demonstrates the issue? it's not obvious by the current bits of code.

Comment: So, while doing what you asked from me, I cleaned some of the code to get it smaller to paste here. It now works after cleaning the code. Seems like the problem was coming from an unused var that I used for testing. Any ideas why it would cause trouble ?

Comment: not right away. You can completely change your question by posting your example that works & the one that doesn't (both as [mcve]) and I'll have a look

Comment: After some further research, it seems that is was one of my string declarations. Before it was : `char str[10];`
After : `char str[10] = "";`

Comment: both aren't equivalent. In the first case `str` value isn't initialized/nul-terminated

Comment: Okay I see now, thanks for your help !